# Why are View animations sometimes clipped?

Tags: android, animation, clipping

I have a FrameLayout containing a subclassed SurfaceView and an ImageView.  I want to do a TranslateAnimation on the ImageView.  The only way I can make it work is to add a vacuous View to the FrameLayout.  Otherwise, the ImageView gets clipped (to the bounds of the ImageView's position at the start of the animation) during the animation.

I'm curious as to why the empty sibling View allows the ImageView to animate correctly.  The line that makes it work is marked with a comment in the code below.

```
public class Test5 extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "Test5";
    private MySurfaceView mMSV;
    private ImageView mRectView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMSV = new MySurfaceView(this);

        mRectView = new ImageView(this);
        ShapeDrawable sd = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
        sd.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
        sd.setIntrinsicWidth(300);
        sd.setIntrinsicHeight(100);
        mRectView.setImageDrawable(sd);

        FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        frameLayout.addView(mMSV);
        frameLayout.addView(mRectView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        // I don't know why the following line prevents clipping during
        // animation. It simply adds a vacuous View.
        frameLayout.addView(new View(this));

        setContentView(frameLayout);
    }  // onCreate

    public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements
            SurfaceHolder.Callback {

        public MySurfaceView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            getHolder().addCallback(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            Canvas can = mMSV.getHolder().lockCanvas();
            can.drawColor(Color.GRAY);
            mMSV.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(can);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                Log.v(TAG, String.format("ACTION_UP, w=%d, h=%d", mRectView
                        .getWidth(), mRectView.getHeight()));
                Animation an = new TranslateAnimation(0f, 200f, 0f, 200f);
                // Animation an = new RotateAnimation(0f, 90f);
                an.setStartOffset(200);
                an.setDuration(1000);
                mRectView.startAnimation(an);
            }
            return true;
        }
    } // MySurfaceView
}  // Test5
```

Answer (score 4):

This is interesting... I guess that the size of the FrameLayout is changed when a vacuous view is added. Your frame layout does not fill the parent, I wonder if you change the layout params to fill parent, what would happen?

I simplified your code to this:

```
    FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this); 

    frameLayout.addView(mMSV); 
    frameLayout.addView(mRectView, 50, 50); 
    frameLayout.addView(new View(this)); //expands frame layout
```

It seems that the FrameLayout size itself equal to the last added child view. If you set addView(new View(this)) before adding a rectangle then it reduces to 50 x 50 and animation is clipped. I assume that addView(new View(this)); expands FrameLayout to the full screen.

Comment: Adding LayoutParams to fill the parent in the `setContentView` call doesn't change anything.

Comment: BTW, changing the SurfaceView to a View causes the problem to go away.

Comment: Shape drawable can be drawn on Canvas or Surface View. In your application you are adding it as a view on top of SurfaceView instead of drawing it, so you are not really utilising your SurfaceView, just using it to detect touch and start animation. Check on android developer how they are using shapeDrawable: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#shape-drawable

Comment: I recommend you go through this tutorial which has 7 parts http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-i,147.html   SurfaceView is usually used when you need to continuosly draw your screen from another thread, for arcade games etc.

Comment: This example is distilled from an app where I do use the SurfaceView for doing (other) animations in a separate thread.  The post http://blog.graphtech.co.il/rotation-and-gl-overlay-in-android/ describes an Android bug that looks very similar to what I'm seeing.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Check the edit of my post. I think you have found a workaround for that bug in the link, so you are doing well after all ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you figured that out, but it seemed to work for me, too.  I had just switched to using a SurfaceView, and noticed that the animations were getting clipped.  Adding an empty View stopped the clipping.

Answer (score 1):

the trick was setting setClipChildren to the 
layout that enclosed the view.